# Different mdadm RAID 1 behavior & performance on CentOS 7 vs CentOS Stream 8

Tags: linux, centos, disk, raid, mdadm

I have 2 basically identical configurations that seem to be handling i/o differently on CentOS 7.9.2009 (3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64) vs CentOS Steam 8 (4.18.0-301.1.el8.x86_64). Both using exact same hardware.

The i/o performance is drastically slower on CentOS 8 and bogs down the whole operating system. The program running writes ~4kb to files every ~50ms and creates new ones every few minutes.

They are both partitioned the exact same:

```
NAME    FSTYPE            LABEL
sda                                                                      
|-sda1  linux_raid_member
| `-md0 ext4              /
|-sda2  linux_raid_member 
| `-md2 swap              [SWAP]
|-sda3  linux_raid_member 
| `-md3 ext4              /home
`-sda4  linux_raid_member 
  `-md4 vfat              /boot/efi
sdb    
|-sdb1  linux_raid_member
| `-md0 ext4              /
|-sdb2  linux_raid_member 
| `-md2 swap              [SWAP]
|-sdb3  linux_raid_member 
| `-md3 ext4              /home
`-sdb4  linux_raid_member 
  `-md4 vfat              /boot/efi
```

md3 ext4 partition has journaling disabled (^has_journal) since that's where all the writes are happening.

Both using mdadm version 4.1 configured the exact same:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.2
ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.2
ARRAY /dev/md/4  metadata=1.0
```

CentOS 7 i/o information (the good/working version):

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.42    0.00    1.73    0.79    0.00   96.06

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               6.57     1.09    6.77   20.33   861.35   181.20    76.93     0.15    5.57    1.80    6.83   1.85   5.03
sda               6.57     1.09    6.89   20.34   871.93   181.20    77.37     0.16    5.73    2.06    6.97   1.86   5.05
md2               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00    36.87     1.94    0.00    0.00    0.00 9189344.91 100.00
md0               0.00     0.00    0.12    2.04     3.04    13.32    15.18     0.38    0.00    0.00    0.00 463.89 100.01
md3               0.00     0.00    0.34   17.24    43.12   165.73    23.76     0.30    0.00    0.00    0.00  56.91 100.02
md4               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     9.63     0.05    0.00    0.00    0.00 1271435.74 100.00
```

Notice the %iowait is relatively low and md devices are at 100 %util vs the sdX at low %util (last column)

CentOS Stream 8 i/o information (newer version of `iostat` so different columns):

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.15    0.00    5.17    8.72    0.00   81.96

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sdb             15.06   51.51   1394.12    266.33     6.74     5.28  30.91   9.29   13.90    8.96   0.67    92.57     5.17   5.65  37.59
sda             15.24   51.52   1407.22    266.33     6.76     5.26  30.73   9.26   13.96    9.11   0.68    92.35     5.17   5.68  37.90
scd0             0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    2.10    0.00   0.00     0.20     0.00   2.80   0.00
md2              0.00    0.05      0.01      0.21     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     6.13     4.00   0.00   0.00
md0              0.16    5.46      5.68     23.85     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00    34.53     4.36   0.00   0.00
md3              0.21   47.99     16.97    239.23     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00    80.54     4.98   0.00   0.00
md4              0.00    0.00      0.02      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     6.01     0.50   0.00   0.00
```

Notice the %iowait is very high and md devices are at 0 %util vs the sdX at higher %util

On `atop` it seems like the CentOS 7 is actually performing worse; the MD devices are flashing red.

```
MDD |          md0  | busy    101% | read       0  |              |  write     29 | KiB/r      0  | KiB/w      4 | MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.0 |               | avq 317813.45 |  avio  345 ms
MDD |          md3  | busy    101% | read       0  |              |  write    518 | KiB/r      0  | KiB/w      7 | MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.4 |               | avq 113304.48 |  avio 19.3 ms
DSK |          sdb  | busy     11% | read       0  |              |  write    551 | KiB/r      0  | KiB/w      7 | MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.4 |               | avq     4.02 |  avio 2.05 ms |
DSK |          sda  | busy     11% | read       0  |              |  write    551 | KiB/r      0  | KiB/w      7 | MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.4 |               | avq     4.35 |  avio 1.94 ms |
```

On CentOS 8 Stream the MD devices are not flashing red as there are at 0%

```
MDD |           md0 |  busy      0%  | read       0  |  write     58  | KiB/r      0  |  KiB/w      4 |  MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.0  |  avq     0.00  | avio  0.0 ns  |
MDD |           md3 |  busy      0%  | read       0  |  write     40  | KiB/r      0  |  KiB/w     22 |  MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.1  |  avq     0.00  | avio  0.0 ns  |
DSK |           sdb |  busy      7%  | read       0  |  write     93  | KiB/r      0  |  KiB/w     12 |  MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.1  |  avq     1.30  | avio 6.97 ms  |
DSK |           sda |  busy      6%  | read       0  |  write     93  | KiB/r      0  |  KiB/w     12 |  MBr/s    0.0  | MBw/s    0.1  |  avq     1.30  | avio 6.58 ms  |
NFS |  rpc        4 |  cread      0  | cwrit      0  |  MBcr/s   0.0  | MBcw/s   0.0  |  nettcp     4 |  netudp     0  | badfmt     0  |  badaut     0  | badcln     0  |
```

On the CentOS 8 `atop` reading, there is also an NFS row, which on CentOS 7 there is not. They both are running an NFS server (same client hardware/system mounted to it), so maybe that is affecting it somehow? The client mounts to `/home/user` (on the md3 partition) which is where all the writes are happening.

Running the same program (rapid small writes) on both systems, `iotop` will show 5-10% I/O usage on CentOS 7, vs 30-80% I/O usage on the CentOS 8 machine. The CentOS 8 machine does also show some I/O usage for [nfsd], but is very low (<4%).

I'm pretty sure the culprit is the CentOS 8 machine writing to sdX for some reason, rather than mdX, but I could also just be totally misunderstanding how MD devices work.